# Child class of Systems.Windows.Forms.TextBox will not let me edit text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, inheritance, textbox

In Visual Studio 2017, I have created a class to inherit System.Windows.Forms.TextBox in its own file under the same namespace for the project. I am only overriding one method ProcessCmdKey() so that I can use ctrl+a keyboard shortcut to select all text in the text box that is created. Multiline textboxes for some reason only does not allow ctrl+a shortcut for whatever reason. When I build the app and run it i am not able to type at all in my child textbox. Here is the class:

```
namespace Amatechtel_Notetaker
{
public class ITextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Control | Keys.C:
                Copy();
                break;
            case Keys.Control | Keys.V:
                Paste();
                break;
            case Keys.Control | Keys.X:
                Cut();
                break;
            case Keys.Control | Keys.A:
                SelectLine();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //selects the current line of text for the formatting methods and allows
    //for formatting shortcuts (e.i. ctrl+c, ctrl+a, ect) to be used.
    internal void SelectLine()
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{HOME}");
        SendKeys.Send("+{END}");
    }
}
}
```

In the Form1.Designer class I am creating an object (field) of ITextBox called notesTextBox which is being used for the main text box for the app. SelectLine() is being used to select the current line the user is editing for a copy button that i have added and have a later implementation for. When I build the project i am not able to type freely in the notesTextBox. If I build the project the same way but using Windows.System.Forms.TextBox object i am able to type freely in the text box. Ctrl+C, V, and X all work in ITextBox but that behavior inherited from the parent. I feel like i am making a simple mistake but anyu help would be great. Please let me know any additional information on the project i need to include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `default: return false;` to your switch. Your current code eats all keypresses.